# IE versions earlier than 9 raises error "Expected identifier, string or number”

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This knockout 2.1 binding expression works fine under Firefox and IE9, but crashes in IE9 compatibility mode with error "*Expected identifier, string or number*”:

```
<div data-bind="template: {
    if: myDataModel, 
    data: myDataModel, 
    afterRender: setup(myDataModel) }">
```

I found actual place under debugger, it's this line of code (knockout-2.1.0.debug.js):

```
return new Function("sc", functionBody)
```

`functionBody` is a string equal to the expression above. I tried to play with spaces and carriage return characters - nothing helps, same results: it works as expected with any browser other than IE9 compatibility mode

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the issue is that older versions of IE don't like "if" or similar reserved words to appear as property names.  Try putting single quotes around the property names.

```
<div data-bind="template: {
'if': myDataModel, 
data: myDataModel, 
afterRender: setup(myDataModel) }">
```

Another common time that you'll have this happen when you have a "class" binding. Same fix:

```
<tr data-bind="attr: { 'class': packageSelected() ? 'success' : '' }">
```

List of reserved words in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: You are totally right, now with `'if'` in expression it works fine. Knockout.js documentation does not mention it, all samples for `if` statement on their web site http://knockoutjs.com given without quotes, though they declare the framework works from IE6+ which seems not to be true

Comment: @YMC: Internally, knockout ensures that all top-level properties in bindings are quoted. It can't do the same for nested object literals. That's why the normal knockout `if` binding seems to work with no problems. You'll just have to get in the habit of quoting the property names for these objects.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado I see, but my complain was not over lack of error messages, it was about lack of quoting `if` statements their own samples on their own web site

Comment: @YMC: well there aren't any examples using the `if` setting for `template` bindings, I only see examples for the normal top-level `if` binding. The documentation should definitely note this.

Comment: I have similar problem with `for` attribute in IE8. If I put it into quotes (`'for'`) I get an error saying `You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element`...